# expansion of #1 in the second argument of \clist_map_inline

Tags: expl3, latex3

There is `\clist_map_inline:Nn <comma list> {<inline function>}` and in `<inline funciton>`, the `<item>` is received as #1. How is #1 expaned to the `<item>`?

The source code of `\clist_map_inline` is

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \clist_map_inline:Nn #1#2
  {
    \clist_if_empty:NF #1
      {
        \int_gincr:N \g__kernel_prg_map_int
        \cs_gset_protected:cpn
          { __clist_map_ \int_use:N \g__kernel_prg_map_int :w } ##1 {#2}
        \exp_last_unbraced:Nco \__clist_map_function:Nw
          { __clist_map_ \int_use:N \g__kernel_prg_map_int :w }
          #1 , \q__clist_recursion_tail ,
        \prg_break_point:Nn \clist_map_break:
          { \int_gdecr:N \g__kernel_prg_map_int }
      }
  }
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the second argument of your wrap command?

Comment: You were missing two backslashes in front of `clist` in the definition of `\test`. More precisely you had `clist_set:Nn` instead of `\clist_set:Nn` and `clist_map_inline:Nn` instead of `\clist_map_inline:Nn`. Once fixed that, the code compiles as expected.

Comment: @egrep I want to know the process of expansion of #1 inside `\clist_map_inline`

Comment: There is no expansion: it's the usual TeX rule for parameters

Comment: @JosephWright I know that `##` is replaced by `#` and `#1` is replaced by the argument, so when `#1` is passed to `\clist_map_inline`, it is not expanded at the first time?

Comment: You should ask a new question, instead of editing the question to a brand new one (see [revisions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/559481/revisions) between 2nd and 3rd version).

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ You're right, but there was no answer at the time of the edit. The closing votes should be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The situation is completely normal TeX handling of `#` tokens, but perhaps it will help to work through the case. We start with `\cs_new_protected:Npn \clist_map_inline:Nn #1#2`, which means that `\clist_map_inline:Nn` has two arguments

- The `clist`
- The code to apply

The latter may contain `#1`, but that does *not* represent the `clist`: we can see that if we use `\tracingall`. There, as we have `#` in an argument, TeX shows it doubled (`##`). That gives a clue as to how this works: `\clist_map_inline:Nn` defines an internal auxiliary, as we can see in the question, which gets represented as taking `##1` (as we are one nesting level). The code we've passed as `#2` for the main function *is* the body of that auxiliary: it picks up each entry as it's `#1`, and that's how things work. No expansion involved, just parameter replacement.